# The map $Φ : SL(2, R) → \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory

I would like to show that the map $$Φ : SL(2, R) → \operatorname{Aut}(H)$$ given by
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{matrix}\right) → f(z)= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
is a group homomorphism.
So, I have to show that $\operatorname{Ker}(\Phi)=\pm I$ and $m(\Phi) = \operatorname{Aut}(H)$. And then the statement follows from the First Group Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: And so, what have you tried ?

Comment: I verified that is an homomorphisme, so $AA^{-1}=I$, but I can't find the $Ker$

Comment: If you just want to say that it's a group homomorphism, you don't have to calculate the kernel. You just have to show that compositions and identities are preserved.

Comment: What group $H$ is?